# c++ threads in wxwidgets and wxwebview

Tags: c++, multithreading, webbrowser-control, wxwidgets, iwebbrowser2

I want to use wxWebview to show some pages during my wxWidgets is working but I have two problems :

1 - I have to do wxWebView::LoadUrl() at the end of the program as when I code some command after it the webbrowser freezes until the commands are done then start to load the url so I can't do any thing after it

2 - due this first problem I get a second problem . I want to load some pages in different times but I can't as I have to load only one page at the end of the program then can't do any thing including loading ather pages .

The solve I wish to do is to make a thread and run the webrowser in it so I can do what I want while the browser loads the pages and can load several pages in various times .

But I tried do it in wxthread but it still runs as the main function and the main function stops until the thread ends .
I need some help .

Comment: can you show some code of what you mean by problem 1? It is not clear exactly what you mean.

Comment: I put my code below